# Clarify on why this wasn't a hardening question?

Tags: discussion

Could I get some clarification of scope for security.stackexchange.

I'd though [my question](https://security.stackexchange.com/revisions/271815/1) was on topic as a "hardening" question, as mentioned in the help.

I don't quite understand what boundary is or why this was off topic. Was this a case that I didn't make the "hardening" component clear enough/early enough in the question? Or is it otherwise off topic to ask how to harden specific software against specific exploits here?

---

As a note, grub questions are better migrated to unix and Linux than super user IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

Whether or not the end result you want is for hardening purposes, the actual usage and configuration of grub is really about Unix and Linux, so I think I agree with you that U&L would have also been a useful option. I went with SU as it was the one the other close voters had already accepted.

Comment: Thanks. I see that reading of it now, although it was not intended to be that. If the question had been centred on an example configuration and asked if that example protected against a specific exploit, would that still have been just a configuration question (off topic) or might that have remained on topic?